# plotting 3 variables using barplot in r

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have an input table of the following :

```
    city    district    shoptype    value
     A      A1           retail     1000
     A      A1        restaurant    200
     A      A2           retail    5000
     A      A2        restaurant    600
     B      A1           retail    2000
     B      A1        restaurant   3000
     B      A2            retail    400
     B      A2        restaurant    500
```

And I wish to plot this using barplot:

```
  X axis: City and District, Y axis: shoptype, size of bar: value
```

May I know how could I do that? I have not been able to plot what I wanted so far using 3 variables...

Pls help!
thanks!

[I've created an example of my desired image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2l7N.jpg)

Adding the dataframe code created by Akrun earlier (thanks Akrun)

```
df1 <- structure(list(city = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
   district = c("A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2"), 
   shoptype = c("retail", "restaurant", "retail", "restaurant", "retail", "restaurant", "retail", "restaurant"), 
   value = c(1000L, 200L, 5000L, 600L, 2000L, 3000L, 400L, 500L)), 
  .Names = c("city", "district", "shoptype", "value"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "y axis: shoptype"? What do you mean by "size of bar" – do you mean the width or the area? Can you provide an image of your expected output (using another program or literally drawing and taking a photo) so that we can have a bit of a better idea what you intend?

Comment: I agree with @Hugh that your description is not clear enough

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (providing d is your data.frame):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=d,aes(x=paste(city,district),y=value,fill=shoptype)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

or

```
gplot(data=d,aes(x=district,y=value,fill=shoptype)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  facet_grid(. ~ city)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question literally, I think you want `width = value` as one of the aesthetics.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = paste0(city, district), y = shoptype, fill = paste0(city, district), width = value)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

However, I think a far more sensible option would be to use a tile:

```
ggplot(df1,
       aes(x = paste0(city, district), 
           y = shoptype, 
           fill = paste0(city, district), 
           width = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks guys for all the help rendered so far, however, it isn't yet what i wanted.. I have created an image but realised i needed 10 reputations to upload an image :(

basically what i wanted was close to Hugh's answer. but the x axis will consist of 1 bar for each district, and both A1 and A2 district will be further grouped by city..

Comment: i tried to edit but i couldnt upload my image... sorry to bother u guys... but how can i upload an image please.... ....

Comment: Upload an image to imgur.com and provide a link. We'll do the rest.